# How do I pass Google maps lat and lng values and save to MySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am writing a Google maps application where the user can click where they want to save a marker by filling a form in an InfoWindow and then clicking a `submit` button which saves the data to a MySQL database.

A picture of what I mean here:

[image: InfoWindow]

I do not know how to retrieve the `lat` and `lng` values from `event.latLng` and then use them as part of my `addLocation` form action.

The JavaScript which contains the `addLocation` form action:

```
function placeMarker(location) {

var latLng = event.latLng;
// don't know how to retrieve lat & lng from latLng?

var contentString = '<form action="addlocation" method="POST">' +
    '<div id="addMarkerInfoWindow">' +
    '<b>Name:</b>&nbsp;<input type="text" name="name"><br>' +
    '<b>Facilities:</b>&nbsp;<input type="text" name="facilities"><br>' +
    '<b>Opening Hours:</b>&nbsp;<input type="text" name="opening"><br>' +
    '<b>Notes:</b>&nbsp;<input type="text" name="notes"><br></div>' +
    '<br><br><input type="submit" value="Submit">&nbsp;' + 
    '<input type="button" value="Cancel" /></form>';

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: contentString
});

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: location,
    map: map
});

infowindow.open(map,marker);

}
```

This is the php code I have:

(**Note:** I am very new to php)

```
<?php

require("db_info.php");

// Opens a connection to a MySQL server
$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', $username);
if (!$connection) {
    die('Not connected : ' . mysqli_error());
}

// Set the active MySQL database
$db_selected = mysqli_select_db($connection, $database);
if (!$db_selected) {
    die('Can\'t use db : ' . mysqli_error());
}

################ Save location #################

if($_POST) //run only if there's a post data
{
    // make sure ajax request
    $xhr = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == 'XMLHttpRequest'; 
    if (!$xhr) { 
        header('HTTP/1.1 500 Error: Request must come from Ajax!'); 
        exit(); 
    }

    // inserting data order
    $order = "INSERT INTO markers (name, facilities, opening, lat, lng, notes) 
        VALUES ('$name', '$facilities', $opening, '$lat', '$lng', '$notes')";

    // declare in the order variable
    $result = mysql_query($order);  //order executes

    if($result) {
       echo("<br>Input data is succeed");
    } else {
       echo("<br>Input data is fail");
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Have you seen this article: [Using PHP/MySQL with Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3)?  Or this one: [From Info Windows to a Database: Saving User-Added Form Data](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlinfo_v3)?

Comment: @geocodezip I had not seen the second link, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update your content string to use hidden fields for `lat` and `lng`

```
var contentString = '<form action="addlocation" method="POST">' +
    '<input type="hidden" name="lat" value="' + location.lat() + '" />' +
    '<input type="hidden" name="lng" value="' + location.lng() + '" />' +
    '<div id="addMarkerInfoWindow">' +
    '<b>Name:</b>&nbsp;<input type="text" name="name"><br>' +
    '<b>Facilities:</b>&nbsp;<input type="text" name="facilities"><br>' +
    '<b>Opening Hours:</b>&nbsp;<input type="text" name="opening"><br>' +
    '<b>Notes:</b>&nbsp;<input type="text" name="notes"><br></div>' +
    '<br><br><input type="submit" value="Submit">&nbsp;' + 
    '<input type="button" value="Cancel" /></form>';
```